# change application icon and application name through localization in Xcode iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, nslocalizedstring

I am working on Localization of my App to support English and Spanish language.I have created the string files for both english and spanish.All the strings in my app are managed by

```
`NSLocalizedString(@"key", nil);`
```

and give the expected result.I have given an option for changing the language inside my app in a tableview.

```
NSUserDefaults *nsdefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
nsdefault setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"en"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
nsdefault synchronize];
```

1) I need to change the app name and icon depending on the selection of language in tableview.For app name i used "CFBundleDisplayName" = "Librairie";
so that the next time i launch the app the app name and icon should change.

2)for app name

```
`"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Librairie";`
```

.It works only if i go to iPhone's setting and change the language manually.Through code it doesn't work.

Please suggest me the approach i can follow so that when i choose spanish language from my tableview the name and icon gets replaced.

can i localize the app icon image also like we do for any image used in UIView ?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't change neither the app icon, neither the display name. Both of those are read only once the app is installed, and even if you could, those would create a really bad user experience.

Comment: You could actually localize your app name using `CFBundleDisplayName` in `*-Info.plist`, and iOS would pick the right name based on your operating system settings every time you change it.

Comment: Yeah, but the question is about changing the application name as a result of a change inside the application, which is still impossible.

Comment: True @Adis, I just wanted to point out that "Both of those are read only once the app is installed” claim isn’t 100% accurate, that’s all. Thanks.